# AngularJS used too much of browser memory, how the garbage collection works in chained filters?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a fairly large dataset to be presented by AngularJS. It took a few seconds to load, instant search works with a bit of sluggish. but after a while, Chrome complains that the script used too much of memory, and asked if continue.

So I examine the process, I have complex filters in ng-repeat, filtering against multiple inputs, sort, paginate, limit, etc.

```
<tr ng-repeat="rec in records | my filter : [model1, model2, model3] | sort: model4 | start: model5 | limit: model6">
```

From what I did, I have to create a new dataset out of input for each filter, like using $.map() or $.grep(), which creates a new object of original dataset. My question is, it should always up until the last filter is finished, the view will be rendered. Then all intermediate dataset clones are to be garbage collected, is it so in angular to handle this? or how I may explicitly gc them?

Or say what is the best practice to do it in Angular?

PS.
Here is an example of how ng filter works:

```
msApp.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        if (!input) return [];
        return input.slice(+start); // +start, parse to int
    };
});
```

So every time model changes, this filter runs and create a new list. And I have couple of them in a chain.

Comment: Your question is: "it should always up until the last filter is finished, the view will be rendered"?

Comment: i am asking if angular taking care of those intermediate clones? Or I should do that, and how?

Comment: you shouldn't create clones at all. If you must - then transform the dataset and store the computed list on the scope. Then use `ng-repeat` with the computed list. This should be much faster and create less garbage. Btw ng-repeat does not create clones. You shouldn't create or modify objects in your custom filters neither.

Comment: @g00fy, to be exact it's the ng-filter within ng-repeat creates intermediate lists. Please see my updated question with an example. every time 'startFrom' filter runs creates a new array out of input. thinking that happens on a large input and through many steps of filtering...

Comment: Each filter is run twice per digest in the view, but only once if you do that filter beforehand in the controller using `$filter('myFilter')(value)`. You can save a lot that way.

Answer (score 0):

I pass some objects through several chained filters (filtering and sorting the elements out), and I just removed the filters to check for the memory consumption differences.

Actually, the application uses less memory when the objects go through the filters than when the filters are not present.

Theese are some of them:

```
<li 
ng-repeat="item in list.items | object2Array | filter:searchItems | orderBy:'data.label'" 
class="status-{{item.data.status}} todo-item" 
title="{{item.data.status}}">
```

`filter` and `orderBy` are the one's that come with Angular, but they don't work on objects (just on arrays), so I made `object2Array`:

```
myApp.filter('object2Array', function() {
    return function(input) {
      var out = [];
      for(i in input){
        out.push(input[i]);
      }
      return out;
    }
  });
```

The objects stored at the original object are preserved, just referenced in another array, so the two way bindings still work.  Not only the other filters now work, but also, somehow, the app is consuming a little less memory now.

Comment: It's obvious that your "out" is taking extra space here. Are you using chrome dev tool to create snapshot for memory consumption test? In my case, I see it increasing constantly. I assume Angular is doing some garbage collection (or making them gc-able) which would be cleaned up by browser at some points. But I have no prove for anything like that.

Comment: But my "out" array seems to be taking very little extra space, as it is just a list of references to the same objects, and not a copy of them.  I assumed that Angular treat object differently when binding them to the view, and so using arrays instead of objects in `ng-repeat` might make it easier for Angular.